# JQuery - Scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scroll bar in javascript / jquery q only when I click on it it jumps local pro click, clicking the tip of the right it automatically jumps to the right and does not stop me drag it to the right ...

FIDDLE: https://fiddle.jshell.net/9xpqq20b/1/